VBA excel to download a docx file through browser needing cookies and varying download time
The sub DownloadPimDoc is called. The Openbrowser opens a basic link to the website which automatically logs in. The Openbrowser2 then goes to the specific download link to start the download. I will later on use the file in VBA but download time varies depending on the server.
Is there a more efficient way to download the file via the browser using VBA?
Sub DownloadPIMDoc(url As String)

    Call OpenBrowser
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue(WaitTime)
    Call OpenBrowser2(url)
    
End Sub

Sub OpenBrowser()
    Dim url As String
    url = "https://website.com"
    ' Open the URL in the default web browser
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=url
End Sub

Sub OpenBrowser2(specificUrl As String)
    
    Dim url As String
    url = specificUrl
    ' Open the URL in the default web browser
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=url
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue(WaitTime)
End Sub

